# Is it possible in android to Intune sdk enabled app authenticate without MSAL or ADAL?

Tags: android, azure-ad-msal, intune

I have integrate intune SDK with MSAL authentication but,Is it possible to android Intune enabled app authenticate without MSAL or ADAL?

Comment: Could you please give some more context, which other libraries do you want to use for auth?

Comment: Did you get any solution? Is it possible to create android app without Client id?